# Is it legal to use a chatbot as a middleman to access the Web?

Tags: internet, is-x-legal, philippines

In my country (Philippines) Facebook Messenger is free, without the images and video. Even if you don't purchase balance data, you can use Messenger as long as you can connect to the internet.

We want to build a Messenger chatbot that could scrape public texts data from the web.

Is this legal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it legal to scrape an individuals' public data from Facebook/Twitter/Instagram?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64282/is-it-legal-to-scrape-an-individuals-public-data-from-facebook-twitter-instagra)

Comment: @BlueDogRanch doesn't seem to

Comment: Presumably this is a matter for your contract with the mobile phone company and Facebook, not a matter of statute law, although asking for help understanding a contract is probably on-topic here. Anyway, Facebook can choose to block your chatbot from Messenger even if your bot is legal. It's unlikely that you'd violate a law, if that's what you're worried about, but that is separate to whether Facebook will let you do it.