Mining product prices in EU marketplaces
Is it legal to slowly mine (scrape product urls I hand picked every day or two by making computer program go to URLs and from loaded HTML document select parts of text for extraction) product prices and estimated delivery terms of products sold in marketplaces by me and competitors? I want to have insights on the products I sell and see how to improve their prices or delivery terms to win buy boxes.

3.1. Website content, i.e. text, graphics, images, trademarks, service marks, logos and other materials are protected by copyright and other legal acts of the European Union and belong to Site owners. Unauthorized use of such content may violate the rights of authors, trademark owners and other legal rights. By using the website, you have no right to sell, change, reproduce, display, publicly perform, distribute, create derivative works or otherwise use the content of the website in any way for any public or commercial purpose. Use of the Website content on any other website or networked computer environment for any purpose is prohibited.

Would it be also legal to share my insights with other businesses for commision?

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/81532/scraping-curating-and-re-publishing-content
